# Spring Security configuration: HTTP 403 error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to secure my website using Spring Security following the guides on the web.

So on my server side I have the following classes.

My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilde rauthManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/course")
public class CourseController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @RequestMapping(value="/course", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Course> get(  // The criterion used to find.
        @RequestParam(value = "what", required = true) String what,
        @RequestParam(value = "value", required = true) String value) {
        //.....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/course", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public List<Course> upload(@RequestBody Course[] cs) {
        
    }
}
```

What confused me very much is the server does not respond to the `POST`/`DELETE` method, while the `GET` method works fine. BTW, I'm using `RestTemplate` on the client side.

Exceptions are:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:574)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:487)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.delete(RestTemplate.java:385)
    at hello.Application.createRestTemplate(Application.java:149)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:99)
```

I've searched the internet for days. Still don't have a clue. Please help. Thanks so much

Comment: is that correct? roles("ADMI N"). There is a space between 'I' and 'N'.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The issue is likely due to [CSRF protection](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/). If users will not be using your application in a web browser, [then it is safe to disable CSRF](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/) protection. Otherwise you should ensure to [include the CSRF token in the request](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/).

To [disable CSRF protection](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/) you can use the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. It is the csrf problem. Yes, I don't want my users to use web browser to using my application. 

It's working well on the client side. But on the server side I get this:

o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Strange.
should I ignore it?

Comment: I think the PageNotFound is a separate issue that I would address. Likely you will need to post another question with more information regarding this error.

Comment: Disabling the `csrf` security config has indeed solved my issue. I find it hard to keep up with all these hidden automatic features brought in by Spring starters.

Comment: Hi everyone, in my case, it was not about csrf. My proxy was forwarding the request to the backend as http instead of https. This also caused 403, and it was hard to track because also spring was refusing requests for POST and DELETE only (so requests that change state) I had to add the forward headers config to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is likely due to CSRF protection, agree with the top comment. Nevertheless, by using this configuration, the method cancells the spring security.

So you can use the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("admin")
                        .password(encoder.encode("admin"))
                        .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                    .withUser("user")
                        .password(encoder.encode("password"))
                        .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue may be related to CSRF or CORS Security Protection.

- FOR CSRF: You can disable it if the application users did not use it from browsers.
- For CORS: You can specify the origin and allow HTTP Methods.

The below code disable CSRF and allow all origins and HTTP methods. so be aware when using it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it dangerous in production to disable csrf()?

Comment: Don't disable csrf. Its a huge security risk. if you don't know this i **HIGHLY** recommend that you go _look up_ what it is before you disable it.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem after upgrading my service to Spring Boot 3. Automatic tests started to fail with a 403 status. After quite a lot of headaches, I found out it is caused by removing trailing slash from URL matching.
[The change is described here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552) So check that you are calling the correct URL.

Wrong:

```
/api/foo/
```

Right:

```
/api/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for days too! Simply disabling CSRF on your configure method with http.csrf().disable(); is all that needed to be done for my put requests to stop receiving 403.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this in case someone else finds it useful in the future. I spent hours looking for what was failing and finally I find the solution, on Postman making a POST to http://localhost:8080/login/ is not the same as making a POST to http://localhost:8080/login (with "/" at the end of request it will return 403 forbidden)

Comment: Nah, this is not the case for me! I had to disable CSRF

Answer (score 0):

Check your token which you are sending through 'Header' and also query in your database for the same token whether that token exist or not.

**Note** : The above is applicable only in case you are using Spring Boot token authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

At present, for Spring Security 6.1.3 the below configuration is sufficient for basic authentication

```
   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)throws Exception {
  httpSecurity.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
  return httpSecurity.build(); }
```

Answer (score -5):

```
http.httpBasic().disable();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll().antMatchers("/*")
     .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin()
     .and().csrf().disable();
http.csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Why there is multiple .csrf().disable() ?