# AJAX / Spring MVC - 403 Forbidden Error without Spring Security

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to make ajax request from my web service with Spring MVC :

```
package com.sid.webService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.sid.dao.entity.Utilisateur;
import com.sid.metier.IMetierUtilisateur;

@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/utilisateurs")
public class webServiceUtilisateur {
     @Autowired
     private IMetierUtilisateur mr;

     @RequestMapping(value="/addUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public boolean addUser(@RequestBody Utilisateur u)
     {
        try
        {
            mr.ajouterUtilisateur(u);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
  }
```

with this AJAX request :

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/addUser",
        headers: { 
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
        type : "POST",
        data : user,
        dataType : "application/json"
}
```

the problem here is the user is login but don't have the right permission , the real issu is that i'm not using spring security , so how block the permission , this is my configuration of spring boot :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ekka-e-commerce
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

error messages :

> - jquery.min.js:2 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/addUser 403.
> - Failed to load http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/addUser: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.

this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sid</groupId>
<artifactId>examplesJavaSpring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ekka-e-commerce</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

can someone tell me what is wrong here, am I doing some mistakes??
thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you do have Spring Security module in your classpath. It enables security by default with SpringBoot auto configurer. Please share your build file (pom.xml or build.gradle)

Comment: thank you @MikhailKholodkov, i update my post up

Comment: did you disable csrf protection? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496356/4437464

Comment: thank you @ElyasEsna , but i'm not using spring security

Answer (score 0):

Do see the Maven Dependencies on whether you have included `spring-security` to your project spring boot will automatically configure spring security without single if you have included in the dependencies .Remove it .It will work after removing .Dependencies will be in `pom.xml`