# are there any security modules in spring boot without spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot version(2.0.1), and I have a problem with security, so when I try to make a request with ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/addUser",
    headers: { 
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
    type : "POST",
    data : user,
    dataType : "application/json"
}
```

i'm getting an HTTP error 403 , i know the meaning of this error ( the user can log in the server but don't have the right permission ) but the problem is i'm not using any module of security this is my dependancy pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

so who can block the request, is there any internal module in spring boot how can enable the security, 
see [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451207/ajax-spring-mvc-403-forbidden-error-without-spring-security)

thank you in advance.

Comment: where does that script reside? Does it come from within your application?

Comment: thank you @MarkoPacak, yes and if you see my previous post, you gonna see the code of the web service.

Comment: looks to me like you are blocked by a CORS filter, which means the script resides outside of your application. but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @MarkoPacak what I can do in this case??

Comment: I downloaded CORS plugin in google chrome, but without success, any suggestion, please ?

Comment: you should first understand what [CORS](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) is, as well as why an OPTION pre-flight request is triggered and why all of this happens. As I said, my best guess is that your web-resources reside outside of the web application, therefore your server doesn't trust it (thankfully). Instead of removing the CORS filter, you should integrate your resources (js, css, ...) to be served by your application. Contrary to what someone pointed out in the other question, CSRF has nothing to do here

Comment: thank you @MarkoPacak, you are a lifesaver !!

Comment: Glad I helped. You might as well answer your own question describing how you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to manage the CORS on the server side with adding ***@CrossOrigin*** annotation to the web service, the web service become like this :

```
package com.sid.webService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.sid.dao.entity.Utilisateur;
import com.sid.metier.IMetierUtilisateur;

@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/utilisateurs")
public class webServiceUtilisateur {

@Autowired
private IMetierUtilisateur mr;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value="/addUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean addUser(@RequestBody Utilisateur u)
{
    try
    {
        mr.ajouterUtilisateur(u);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }   
  } 
}
```

and if you want more customization, add all the domains you are going to be accessing your spring backend from, and make them in the attribute origins  like this :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/")
@RequestMapping(value="/addUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean addUser(@RequestBody Utilisateur u)
{
    try
    {
        mr.ajouterUtilisateur(u);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }   
  } 
}
```