# Unexpected 403 error when using Spring Security

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, spring-boot

Here I have the html code for a form. A form to create an event. It asks the user for a few information and after that he has to press the button create .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body class="container">

<nav th:replace="fragments :: header"></nav>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name
            <input th:field="${event.name}" class="form-control">
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.name}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description
            <input  th:field="${event.eventDetails.description}" class="form-control">
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventDetails.description}"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact Email
            <input  th:field="${event.eventDetails.contactEmail}" class="form-control">
        </label>
        <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventDetails.contactEmail}"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category
            <select th:field="${event.eventCategory}">
                <option th:each="eventCategory : ${categories}"
                        th:value="${eventCategory.id}"
                        th:text="${eventCategory.name}"
                ></option>
            </select>
            <p class="error" th:errors="${event.eventCategory}"></p>

        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I have the java code for my form .

```
    @GetMapping("create")
    public String displayCreateEventForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("title", "Create Event");
        model.addAttribute(new Event());
        model.addAttribute("categories", eventCategoryRepository.findAll());
        return "events/create";
    }

    @PostMapping("create")
    public String processCreateEventForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Event newEvent, Errors errors, Model model){
        if (errors.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("title", "Create Event");
            return "events/create";
        }
        eventRepository.save(newEvent);
        return "redirect:";
    }
```

I don't know why after button is pressed it gives me an error like  :

> White label Error Page .
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

> Tue Dec 29 00:24:57 EET 2020
> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Forbidden.

The configuration class

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/registration**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Security?

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Security

Comment: So post your `@Configuration` class

Comment: So it seems like you secured the endpoint of submiting the form and tried to access it unauthorized. Permit the form only after authorization or remove its path from SecurityConfig.

Comment: Spring security requires all post requests to have csrf by default. Either add a csrf parameter (recommended) or disable csrf (not recommended). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496356/10871900).

Comment: Now I changed the configure method and i put : http.csrf().disable();   . But now it jumps over the login part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@dan1st* mentioned it in the comment section, `CSRF` is required in all form submission when using SpringSecurity (unless you disable it). To automatically add `csrf token` in your form, a simple way is by using thymeleaf tags. As soon as thymeleaf detect its tags in a form, it will add csrf token in a hidden input when missing.
Here is an example

```
<form th:action="@{'your_post_path'}" method="POST" th:object="${yourModelAttributeEntity}">
...
</form>
```

You can add one of them or both

Comment: Okay cool. You can mark the answer as the correct one to help future readers