# Post permit all don't took in consideration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring security, I try to allow a post without need to be connected.

So in a class who extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/help**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/printdownload**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout();
}
```

When I try to call this controller

```java
@PostMapping("/printdownload")
public String printTestament(@RequestBody TestamentWizard testamentDocuement){
   ...
}
```

I get this

```
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /printdownload
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/printdownload
 o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
 o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
 o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /login] with attributes [permitAll]
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
 s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Just don't understand why post is secured when i specified to permit it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring security 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468209/spring-security-403-error)

Comment: that specify to disable csrf, not really the solution to go

Comment: Then you have to send CSRF token with your request.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security secures requests through [defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)). Because of this, access rules like `permitAll()` and `authenticated()` are not the only thing protecting the web application.

In your case, CSRF protection is rejecting the request because it is enabled by default along with other [protection against exploits](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/index.html). You can read about [CSRF protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html) and why `POST` requests require a CSRF token in the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html).